# What are the methods on SpringBoard to handle the life cycle of application?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, springboard

Or maybe there is some method will accept the notification of an application's life cycle notification. What is the SpringBoard equivalent of methods like `application: didEnterBackground`?

Comment: Hey, did my answer help you?  Feel free to follow up with any questions, or [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you are satisfied.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `-(void)frontDisplayDidChange:(id)arg1;` found in the [SpringBoard header](http://developer.limneos.net/?framework=SpringBoard&header=SpringBoard-Class.h).  From the [iPhoneDevWiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SpringBoard):

> Whenever a different app is displayed, `frontDisplayDidChange:(id *)newDisplay` is called. newDisplay is a reference to the `SBApplication` of the displayed app if the app was switched to, or it is `nil` if the homescreen is now showing. However, in some situations, it may be a reference to a `UIViewController`. For example, when the lockscreen is shown, `newDisplay` references an instance of `SBLockScreenViewController`.

Additional related methods:

```
-(id)_accessibilityFrontMostApplication; // returns an SBApplication reference
-(id)_accessibilityTopDisplay; // returns an SBDisplay reference
-(id)_accessibilityRunningApplications; // returns an array of SBApplication references
-(BOOL)_accessibilityShouldAllowAppLaunch;
-(BOOL)_accessibilityShouldAllowIconLaunch;
-(BOOL)_accessibilityObjectWithinProximity;
```